# Should we upgrade Flash player always upon new release?

Tags: windows-xp, flash-player

Should we upgrade Flash player always upon new release? or it can create problem . Does every new flash player support files made for all previous version of Flash player?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does every new flash player support files made for all previous version of Flash player?

Yes, they are always backwards-compatible (or at least have been so far). Flash Player 10 can still play animations made in Flash 2.

> Should we upgrade Flash player always upon new release?

Absolutely. You get new features, better performance, added security, etc. There are no drawbacks that I can think of. What do you have to lose?

Comment: The security is the thing really. Really that's the reason you would upgrade.